# How to print names from a text file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have got a text document that looks something like this

```
Kei 1 2 3 4 5
Igor 5 6 7 8 9
Guillem 8 7 6 9 5
```

How can I print their names and their last 3 scores

I came up with this

```
class_3 = open('class_3','r')
read = class_3.read()
read.split()
print(read)
```

But it came out with just

```
K
```

Please help

Comment: Thanks @Kasramvd, but how do I put their names in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can loop over file object and split the lines, then use a simple indexing to print the expected output:

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        print items[0], ' '.join(items[-3:])
```

Output :

```
Kei 3 4 5
Igor 7 8 9
Guillem 6 9 5
```

The benefit of using `with` statement for opening the file is that it will close the file at the end of the block automatically.

As a more elegant approach you can also use unpacking assignment in python 3.X:

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, *rest = line.split()
        print(name, ' '.join(rest))
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.x you will have to change @Kasramvd's answer slightly. You have to add parenthesis around the parameters of the call to the print function.

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        print(items[0], ' '.join(items[-3:]))
```

Comment: In python 3 you can use unpacking assignment `name, *rest = line.split()` then `print(name, '  '.join(rest)`

Comment: IMO this is not a real separate answer but rather should be a comment to Kasramvd's answer...

Comment: There are plenty of good answers on SO that expand on previous answers. The tag on the question is Python 3.x thus it is valid to clarify. There is also a specific rule to allow duplicate answers (which this isn't). Thanks for the feedback though.